# Adblock Plus: What is the reason this rule doesn't work?

Tags: firefox, adblock

I've always been confused by [ABP syntax](https://help.eyeo.com/adblockplus/how-to-write-filters#basic) for blocking content, but usually I can get what I need. But I've struggled a couple of hours trying to understand how to block this image:

[image]

(actual URL: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5e056be276ae8f3e942b01db4740cb99?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1)

which appears on this page:

[image]
(actual URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11816060/user-12)

I wanted to use a filter to block all images from URLs starting by `www.gravatar.com/avatar/` (embedded in any page/domain) and expected this to work:

`https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/`
(or more simply `www.gravatar.com/avatar/`)

But it doesn't. ABP proposes this filter:

`stackoverflow.com##img[src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5e056be276ae8f3e942b01db4740cb99?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"]`

which is indeed more specific and works.

What am I doing wrong in widening the rule?

Comment: Adblock Plus tries to suggest the most specific filter it can in order to avoid blocking stuff that the user might not want to block. Keeping filters as narrow as possible is a good rule of thumb when writing filters. That being said, if you intentionally want to block multiple things and you know that nothing else than avatars are coming from this URL it's totally fine to create such a filter.

Comment: @greiner: Do you have an idea of the reason why widening ABP selective suggestion, by removing the domain and the specific image url (to block all avatars, and possibly other stuff -- that's fine -- from Gravatar, at all domains) doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for misreading the question. I looked into it (using the Adblock Plus panel in the browser's developer tools window) and found that there's an exception rule in the EasyList filter list (namely `@@||gravatar.com/avatar$image,third-party`) which prevents those requests from being blocked. Unfortunately, there's currently no way to overrule it but you can report it to the EasyList authors at https://github.com/easylist/easylist/issues and/or create an element hiding filter to at least hide the image.

Comment: @greiner: Very good find! Thanks. I may also block images from the site [using Firefox itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxgQl.png) (though I haven't checked if the resource is only hidden or really not fetched). I'm surprised there is an exception for gravatar.com in EasyList, [gravatar is suspected to be a big tracking site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/is-gravatar-a-privacy-risk) (the 32-char identifier of an image -- that's 3.4e38 identifiers -- seems indeed far from being necessary, unless they want to be able to track each molecule at the surface of Earth ...)

Comment: The Firefox option sounds like it will block them but probably only on stackoverflow.com. Regarding Gravatar's privacy risk, it's much smaller than what a script could do (i.e. Facebook like button, Disqus comments widget) but the best advice I can give is to check out [its privacy policy](https://automattic.com/privacy/) to decide for yourself whether the risk outweighs the value it adds.